# Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction:

Tags: web3j, pending-transactions, java

I am sending a transaction through this code:

```
            txhash = careercertificate
                .createCertificate(id, fecha, nombre, rutalumno, instituto, rutinstituto, titulo, totalhash, fechatitulacion, registronumber, codigoV)
                .send().getTransactionHash();
```

And I return this exception, my application has it on a tomcat server but the tomcat does not receive it for timeout exception, how could txhash return to the tomcat?

```
org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction:0x625261.....
```

Comment: could you please add more details, like are you using ganache or something else, which version of web3j, which version of solc?

Comment: I am using web3j 3.5.0 in java with maven, the pragma of my contract is 0.4.23.

Comment: and on testnet or rinkeby or Ganache :)? your transactionHash could be the 0x625261....  but you are not getting the receipt :/

Comment: I'm working on the network rinkeby and mainnet, the issue is that I want to lower those 600 seconds to 60 seconds, I have a try-catch that handles that exception, but that waiting time, is because I expect it to be successful the transaction.

Comment: then you should modify the default "transactionManager" and "Transaction Receipt Processors", I'm not very familier with that sorry , but you could start here , look for those 2 key words under https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smart_contracts.html